# Is there any way to show the Google Cloud Build Data on a separate Dashboard?

Tags: dashboard, google-cloud-build

I am using Google Cloud build for auto-build process. I want to create a dashboard which shows the trigger details and logs on which I worked on.
I know about Stack Driver but need suggestions other than that.

Answer (score 0):

You could use Google's APIs to list or describe the builds and also to get the information you want about the triggers. The [Viewing build results documentation](https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/view-build-results) explains what kind of information you can retrieve, but I always suggest playing around with [Google's API Explorer](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/cloudbuild/v1/).